# I need help with Pilfering perfume quest

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Pilfering Perfume quest, how do I find crown chemical company outside Stormwind city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Pilfering Perfume quest to be completable, the Valentine's day event needs to be active. Once this event is active, the NPCs can be located just outside Stormwind, to the left behind the main gate when exiting Stormwind.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to wait until close to Valentine's day or just abandon it.